# About structure SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES

Tags: windows, handle, inheritance

Reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379560(v=vs.85).aspx, I don't really understand the role of bInheritHandle. It's stated as: "A Boolean value that specifies whether the returned handle is inherited when a new process is created. If this member is TRUE, the new process inherits the handle." Inherit? What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a kernel object (like process, thread, event) in Windows you can specify if the object handle can be inherited by a child process when it creates new process.
Assume that you have a process `A` and it calls CreateEvent to create an event. The handle is only accessible inside `A`. Now when `A` creates a new process `B` via CreateProcess you can specify if `B` can also access the event object. If you want to make `B` access the object you must set `bIneritHandles` to TRUE in CreateProcess arguments **AND** make each object to be inheritable via SECURITY_ATTRIBUTE's `bInheritHandle`. In this case you must pass SECURITY_ATTRIBUTE with `bInheritHandle=TRUE` to CreateEvent call.